# Auto-Scaling Scatter Plot Axis Based on Input Data

Tags: math, scientific-computing

I am writing a module that creates a scatter plot from a 2 dimensional array of numbers provided by the user (x and y values). It is intended that the graph axis will be scaled to the value required to encompass all the input numbers, while also rounding to an aesthetically pleasing value. For example, if the maximum value entered is 4.56, I would like it to round the maximum axis value to 5. If the maximum value is 850, I'd like it to round the axis to 1000.

This initially seems like a simple task. Simply take the max value and round up. However, what makes it difficult is my module could be dealing with input values as small as 0.00000001 or as large as many billions.

Can anyone suggest a workflow for making this happen? I don't need the code itself, just the process required. The only way I have come up with is an extremely cumbersome iterative approach that still handles unusual values rather poorly.

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: Set y-max to `10^ceiling(log10(max))` ?  This doesn't quite satisfy your first example, but might get you started.

Comment: Thanks, that just about does it!